# Adding a sound to the onClick method

Tags: java, android

I would like to add a sound whenever the user clicks the apps button, any idea how can I do that?
 I have tried to create a "raw" directory on the res/ file with different names, like for example "test.mp3", which did not work...

Comment: Show some code. Saying you have "tried to play a sound" isn't really very specific, since that's your whole question. How did you try to play that MP3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing sound is not difficult.
And as long as these are short sounds during app foreground operations it fine.
You need to use the MediaPlayer.
First, prepare it.

```
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

    private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mOnCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                mMediaPlayer.release();

                mMediaPlayer = null;
            }
        }
    };
```

Now on click:

```
public void onItemClick(.........) {

                releaseMediaPlayer();
                mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(),getSoundFileResID());
                mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mOnCompletionListener);
                mMediaPlayer.start();
```

}

You need to implement the getSoundFileResID().
For more info read the [MediaPlayer OverView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer)